# onclick function on a radio or checkbox input?

Tags: javascript, input

Is it possible to have a function execute when a radio or checkbox is clicked?

I tried this:

```
<input name="email_notification" id="email_not1" type="radio" class="form_radio" onclick="select_on()" value=1 <?PHP echo $on;?>>
```

It doesn't work. I could wrap it in a label and put the onclick function on that, but I need it only on the radio button and not the label. Is this possible?

UPDATE:

Thanks for your answers! I tried it with another function and it worked fine. Part of the original function was to set the checkbox to "checked" and apparently that was conflicting with it. I made a duplicate function with that part removed and it works fine. :)

Comment: What should the function do? Why is there the PHP part? It is definitely possible, try to exchange `onclick="select_on()"` for `onclick="alert('hello')"` and you will see that it works.

Comment: you have a function named **select_on**?

Comment: onclick works fine with radiobutton, may be the error its on other part of your code

Comment: You chould be using the `onchange` event

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a suitable description. What doesn't work? What errors do you get? What messages are in the console? Where is *select_on* defined? What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, and normally yes. If the Javascript function is declared properly and/or file containing the function is included properly on the page. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jLt9ce1y/1/):

```
<input name="email_notification" id="email_not1" type="radio" class="form_radio" onclick="select_on()">

<script>
    function select_on() {
        alert('Hello');
        // do whatever you want here.
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet works for me. You might have a trigger attached to this element, and that can eat up your default event handling.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, you have errors elsewhere or there's an element on top of your checkbox and you're not really clicking on it.

See it here:

```js
function select_on() {
  alert('it works!');
}
```

```html
<input name="email_notification" id="email_not1" type="radio" class="form_radio" onclick="select_on()" value=1 />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="email_notification" id="email_not1" type="radio" class="form_radio" onclick="select_on(this)">

<script>
    function select_on(node) {
        if(node.checked) {
           alert('checked true');
        } else {
           alert('checked false');
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery change function here.

Sample code:

```
$('input:radio[name="email_notification"]').change(function() {

//do whatever you need here

});
```

Or if you want to trigger a function for every clicks you can simply use:

```
$('input:radio[name="email_notification"]').click(function() {

    //do whatever you need here

    });
```